# Why is my C# Regular Expression not matcing between lines?

Tags: c#, regex, multiline

I have the following Regex in C#:

```
Regex h1Separator = new Regex(@"<h1>(?'name'[\w\d\s]+?)(<br\s?/?>)?</h1>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Trying to match a string that looks like this:

```
<h1>test content<br>
</h1>
```

right now it matches strings that look like the following:

```
<h1>test content<br></h1>
<h1>test content</h1>
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I be matching for a newline character? If so, what is it in C#? I can't find one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't check for whitespace between the end of the br tag and the start of the next tag, so it expects to see the hr tag immediately after. Add a \s* in between to allow that.

Answer (score 1):

You have it defined as a single line regex, see the `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag :) use `RegexOptions.Multiline`

Comment: I suppose I should have said, but neither option works. Any chance that there is something wrong with the regex itself?

Comment: Singeline only controls the behavior of the . element (whether it matches everything or everything except newline). He doesn't use the . element in his regex so it shouldn't change anything.

Comment: and Multiline just "Changes the meaning of ^ and $ so that they match at the beginning and end, respectively, of any line, not just the beginning and end of the whole string." (from MSDN). Seems there's a lot of confusion over these two RegEx options.

Answer (score 0):

The newline character in C# is: `\n`. However, I am not skilled in regex and couldn't tell you what would happen if there was a newline in a regex expression.

Answer (score 0):

you can either add a dot `.` to your string before the ending `</h1>` and keep the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option, or change it to `RegexOptions.Multiline` and add a `$` to the regex before the `</h1>`.  details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Use the Multiline flag.  (Edit to address my mispeaking about the .Net platform).

Singleline mode treats the entire string you are passing in as one entry.  Therefore `^` and `$` represent the entire string and not the beginning and ending of a line within the string.  Example `<h1>(?'name'[\w\d\s]+?)(<br\s?/?>)?</h1>` will match this:

```
<h1>test content<br></h1>
```

Multiline mode changes the meaning of `^` and `$` to the beginning and ending of each line within the string (i.e. they will look at every line break).

```
Regex h1Separator = new Regex(@"<h1>(?'name'[\w\d\s]+?)$(<br\s?/?>)?</h1>", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

will match the desired pattern:

```
<h1>test content<br> 
</h1>
```

In short, you need to tell the regex parser you expect to work with multiple lines.  It helps to have a regex designer that speaks your dialect of regex.  There are many.

Comment: This isn't true. See the documentation on RegexOptions.Singleline.

Comment: This is not true. have a look in the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx)

Comment: This is where working on multiple platforms gets you.  The OP still needs to use the Multiline flag,  and insert the `$` to the end of the first line in the regex.

Comment: $ is an anchor, so I don't think this will do what you expect.

Comment: `$` is a zero-width assertion; it asserts that, *if* there is a next character, that character must be a linefeed.  But it doesn't *consume* the character; you still have to do that the old-fashioned way, with `\n`, or `\s`, or even `.` in Singleline mode.  Where you used it, the next character has to be `<`, so it will never match.